# Passing values in C++

Tags: c++, io, readfile

I have a function that reads some variables from a file:

```
void ReadFromFile(const string& inicod){
string buf;
ifstream infile(inicod);

infile >> N; getline(infile, buf);
infile >> t_end; getline(infile, buf);
infile >> L; getline(infile, buf);
...
```

I must access these variables N, t_end, L in main. Where should I declare them (like global variables?) and how can I access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a tuple.

```
auto ReadFromFile(const string& inicod){
  string buf;
  ifstream infile(inicod);

  infile >> N; getline(infile, buf);
  infile >> t_end; getline(infile, buf);
  infile >> L; getline(infile, buf);

  return std::make_tuple(N, t_end, L);
}
```

The `auto` means that the return type of the function depends on the return statement. So whatever I pass `std::make_tuple`, the function will automatically return the correct `std::tuple<T1, T2, ..., Tn>` (the result of `std::make_tuple`).
`std::tuple` is a neat template that lets you bundle data together on-the-fly without having to declare your own `struct`. If your returned objects aren't costly to default construct, there's also a utility to unpack tuples:

```
//N, t_end, L definition
std::tie(N, t_end, L) = ReadFromFile(inicod);
```

Comment: Thats not easy to understand for a beginner without any explanation, as for the auto type

Comment: @Treycos, `auto` return types of all things? I'd have thought that `std::tuple<type_of_N, type_of_t_end, type_of_L>` would be much more to chew on.

Comment: It is, i just meant that it was better to explain why you were using auto instead of that, but nvm ;)

Comment: @Treycos, added a short paragraph. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @colombien, if this works for you, consider accepting the answer (mark the V under the voting buttons), to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer a reference to the variable like:

```
void ReadFromFile(const string& inicod,string &N,string &e_end,string &L){

....
}
```